# Obtain Memory details as shown in DDMS perspective

Tags: android

**I have the following memory details from the DDMS perspective of Eclipse.**

[image]

**However in spite of implementing the following code, I'm unable to obtain the values shown in the above image.**

```
private void logHeap() {

        long maxMemory = Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()/ (1024*1024);
        long totalMemory = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() / (1024*1024);

        long heapSize = Debug.getNativeHeapSize()/(1024*1024);
        long allocatedHeapSize = Debug.getNativeHeapAllocatedSize() / (1024*1024);
        long freeHeapSize = Debug.getNativeHeapFreeSize() / (1024*1024);


        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
        df.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
        df.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);

        Log.d(TAG, "debug. =================================");
        Log.d(TAG,"Max memory: "+df.format(maxMemory)+" MB");
        Log.d(TAG,"Total memory: "+df.format(totalMemory)+" MB");

        Log.d(TAG,"Heap Size: "+df.format(heapSize)+" MB");
        Log.d(TAG,"Allocated Heapsize: "+df.format(allocatedHeapSize)+" MB");
        Log.d(TAG,"Free Heapsize: "+df.format(freeHeapSize)+" MB");
    }
```

**I'm getting the following values:**

```
Max Memory : 36.00MB
Total Memory : 7.00 MB
Heap Size : 3.00 MB
allocated heapsize : 3.00 MB
free heapsize : 0.00 MB
```

**Are there any other APIs to obtain the details?**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298208/how-to-discover-memory-usage-of-my-application-in-android/2299813#2299813

Comment: Also, the native heap is not the same as the managed heap.  You're comparing apples to oranges.